# How to calculate the flux through complicated surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, divergence-operator

> How can I find the integral $\int_{S} 2~dydz + 1~dzdx - (3x)~dxdy$, where $S$ is the following surface?
>
> $$x^2 + 2y^2 + 3z^2 + xyze^{(x+y+z)\sin(x^2 -y+z)} = 1$$
>
> $$0\leq x,y,z$$

I think that I must use Gauss's law, but I am not sure if the surface is closed. I thought if it isn't I shall close it with a sphere with radius $\epsilon$.

Then I simply calculate the flux through the ball and say:

$$\int_{S}F\cdot\vec{n} = \int_{Ball+S}F\cdot\vec{n} - \int_{Ball}F\cdot\vec{n} = 0 \:(\text{Gauss's law}) - \int_{Ball}F\cdot\vec{n}$$

> If I can't use Gauss's law, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Your surface is not closed. Its traces on the $OXY$, $OXZ$ and $OYZ$ planes are quarters of ellipses. You can make it closed by adding the coordinate planes. Your total flux through the closed surface is zero by Gauss' Theorem, so the flux through your surface is the opposite of the flux through the elliptical pieces of coordinate planes that you added. The latter is easily found as double integrals.

Comment: i dont understand your analysis , how did you know that it isn't closed ?

Comment: you said that $ x=0 $ gives you an ellipse , $ y =0$ gives you an ellipse and $ z = 0$ gives you an ellipse on $[YZ]$ , $[XZ]$ , $[XY]$ but how did you know that its not closed

Comment: Those elliptical intersections with the coordinate planes constitute the boundary of your surface, therefore it is not closed. A way to visualize it is the following: imagine the eight of an ellipsoid centered at the origin of coordinates (in canonical position) contained in the first octant. Your surface is a complicated surface that has the same elliptical intersections with the planes as the aforementioned ellipsoid.

Comment: Your surface is contained in the first octant, so it has edges on the coordinate planes.

Comment: oh nice i got it thank you